# AS3 I can't get removeChild to delete my items when they are listed in Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, adobe-animate

using ActionScript 3 on Animate, I'm trying to delete a bunch of items from the stage using  `Array` and  `for` loop. I actually downloaded this code from this site, but it doesn't seem to work for me. It will only delete one item and won't delete the others. and when I redraw the stage it will then not delete anything at all. I have another function button down the road that will restart (redraw) the game, I'm using the `gotoAndPlay()` to redraw.  FYI, the "squares" are sprites and the "myTFs" are text fields that are 'paired' together to become buttons. What am I doing wrong?

```
function mainFunc(): void {
    var btnsArray: Array = new Array("square", "myTF3", "square2", "myTF2", "square4", "myTF4");
    for (var ii = 0; ii < btnsArray.length; ii++) {
        removeChildAt(btnsArray[ii]);
        btnsArray.length = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`removeChildAt()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChildAt()) takes an integer index. You're giving it a string. Use [`getChildByName()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()) and [`removeChild()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChildAt())

Comment: Also, you set the **Array**'s length to zero on the first iteration, there's nothing in that **Array** after the first go.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an **Array** of **DisplayObject**'s names you want to batch operate (e.g. remove from display list or something else) you can do the following:

```
var A:Array = ["square", "myTF3", "square2", "myTF2", "square4", "myTF4"];

// Iterate over items of the Array.
for each (var aName:String in A)
{
    // Obtain a reference to the object by its instance name.
    var aChild:DisplayObject = getChildByName(aName);
    
    // Check if it is a valid instance before removing to avoid errors.
    if (aChild)
    {
        removeChild(aChild);
    }
}
```